# Simple SQL nested select query no longer working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, view, nested

I have a relatively simple query which usually takes no longer than about 10 seconds to return. It is as follows:

```
SELECT personid 
FROM vw_has_copyright 
WHERE (Orderid IN (SELECT orderid 
                   FROM orders WHERE eventid = 1234)) 
GROUP BY personid 
ORDER BY personid
```

Now it just hangs when I run this query. If I run `select orders.orderid from orders where orders.eventid = 1234` - and then use the list generated from this query with the `select personid from vw_has_copyright where Orderid in (*my list here...*)` it works fine.

So why is it no longer working with the nested select query? It seems so strange but I'm not sure how to go about debugging it? Thanks in advance!!

---EDIT---

Rather embarassingly, the problem was that I haven't been maintaining my indexes properly. Due to high fragmentation on my orders table indexes the query suddenly stopped working, however after rebuilding and reorganising them the query now works again! Moral of the story - look after your database!!

Comment: Which DBMS? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: What version of SQL?  (MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle?)  I'd look into refreshing table statistics and/or recompiling the view *(assuming vw_ means view)*.

Comment: What's the execution plan, and when did you last perform index maintenance and update statistics?

Comment: If it suddenly "hangs" it's might be a locking problem. Some other transaction modified vw_has_copyright or the orders table and that blocks your select

Comment: Can hardly believe it - but my SQL server agent maintenance plan has been inactive (for what must have been some time) as there was a very high amount of fragmentation on my indexes. I just rebuilt and reorganised the relevant indexes and all is working fine now!

Answer (score 1):

`IN` is very tricky, specially on a orders table that usually have a huge amount of records. I suggest changing it to EXISTS or even a regular join.

[Here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/18/60210.aspx) is a very good link that explains the difference between these 3 operands

Comment: thanks for the info - while it wasn't technically the solution to my problem i'm having a read now and it's useful to know!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT CopyRight.personid 
FROM vw_has_copyright CopyRight
     Inner Join orders order on order.orderid = CopyRight.Orderid
WHERE  order.eventid = 1234
GROUP BY CopyRight.personid 
ORDER BY CopyRight.personid
```

Answer (score 0):

You should perform index maintenance and statistics updates regularly to ensure queries perform consistently.

It is also important to check the execution plan to see if SQL Server is doing anything unexpected (table scan vs. index seek).